# Anaconda navigator on WSL2g on Windows 11

Tags: windows, anaconda, wsl-2

after a successful installation of Anaconda following the procedure:https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu/

when closing and restarting a terminal window and typing the command:

anaconda-navigator

an error message about listing display settings appears and a little anaconda navigator icon apoeara on the taskbar, but it is minimized and unsuable (nothing displayed)

Also, I noticed that when launching python in the base conda env and importing matplotlib and plotting a dummy function the same behaviour occurs: minimized icon on the taskbar but no display (not usable)...

I wonder if its one of these  "nightmare" config things with Qt backend or something related to graphics backends that is not configured properlyby default?

note that I just installed Windows 11 and WSL2 and the other GUI Linux apps work fine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can first update your WSL to the latest version (mine is 5.10.102.1 kernel version in Win11). And install one of the recommended app in the following link, eg. apt-get install gedit. The GUI dependencies will be automatically installed.   Then you can use command "conda activate", and "anaconda-navigator" to open the GUI app. Follow the official installation guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

You can start with gedit to test the successful installation of the GUI support of the WSL. There could be some warring show up, but nothing critical in my case. You probably should restart WSL after a apt update/dist-upgrade/install to make sure everything is installed properly.
Here is a screenshot after successful installation.
[start gedit and Anaconda Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvjGu.png)